# Getting "not a function"error in React Native/Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

My code is [here](https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4)

I am getting the error below.

I believe its something to do with the employee create line in the code below and i cannot figure out why this might be happening. I am doing this from a [tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/t/lecture/5870550?start=405)

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Picker, Text } from 'react-native';
import { employeeUpdate, employeeCreate } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';

class EmployeeCreate extends Component {
  onButtonPress() {
    const { name, phone, shift } = this.props;

    this.props.employeeCreate({ name, phone, shift: shift || 'Monday' });
  }
  render() {
    return (
    //
    // <View>
    //  <Text>Employees</Text>
    // </View>
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Name"
            placeholder="Jane"
            value={this.props.name}
            onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'name', value })}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Phone"
            placeholder="555-555-5555"
            value={this.props.phone}
            onChangeText={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'phone', value })}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <Text style={styles.pickerLabelStyle}>Pick a Shift: </Text>
        <Picker
            //style={{ flex: 1 }}
            selectedValue={this.props.shift}
            onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 'shift', value })}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday" />
          <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="Sunday" />
        </Picker>
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
        <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            Create
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
const styles = {
  pickerLabelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20
  }
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { name, phone, shift } = state.employeeForm;

    return { name, phone, shift };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  employeeUpdate, employeeCreate
})(EmployeeCreate);
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Folks- this is resolved. I found my answer.

In the 
https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4/blob/master/src/actions/index.js

file. I was not exporting all the actions from the Employeeactions file and so was not exporting the employeeCreate action. i should have put a * there.

Issue is resolved! Thanks!